# Sympy simple relational expressions with assumptions

Tags: sympy, inequality

I would like to solve simple inequality expressions with sympy (or any other package). In my use case, all variables are real and positive.

Simple examples like :

```
from sympy.assumptions import assuming, Q, ask,refine
import sympy

x,y,z = sympy.symbols("x,y,z",nonnegative=True,real=True)
ask(y<x,Q.gt(x,y))
```

I get solved, but as soon as I already try the following modification:

```
ask(y/z<x/z, Q.gt(x,y) & Q.gt(z,0))
```

it does not work anymore. Unfortunately I find relatively few examples online and due to the system change in sympy I am quite confused.

Can someone provide me with simple examples with explanation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry, I got messages mixed up: for this post my comment was that neither `ask(y/2<x/2, Q.gt(x,y))`, nor `ask(y+1<x+1, Q.gt(x,y))`, not even `ask(y<x+1, Q.gt(x,y))` are resolved; I tried adding `finite=True` in the `symbols` but it doesn't help